# How to get Google logged in user's details in Spring Boot web-app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I am implementing google login using OAuth2 in Spring Boot web-app. Now I am stuck, as I don't know how to get user details. Using `Authentication` or `Principal` object I can only get  username(which is some random number) with method `princial.getname()` method and there are no other relevant methods to get the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the OAuth2 framework is designed to be generic, you will not find methods for anything other than the principal name. Instead, the `OAuth2User` class has a `getAttributes` method which returns the attributes from the user info URI of the specific provider as a map. This is how you get the user object of the current request

```java
@GetMapping("/user/me")
public Map<String, Object> userDetails(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User user) {
    return user.getAttributes();
}
```

Try this and you will see which exact attributes Google supports.